# Trouble with connection between Apache Airflow and AWS Glue

Tags: airflow, aws-glue

I start locally on my virtual machine Apache Airflow and i want to connect to Amazon Glue jobs to run them.
Source code i got from pull-request: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3504/files

So what connections(in Airflow UI) should i establish to run the Amazon Glue jobs? Can you advise me some documentation? Because i haven't found anything helpful in official docs.

For dag i use simple code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.aws_glue_operator import AWSGlueJobOperator
def print_hello():
    return 'Hello hello!'

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple glue DAG',
          schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 6, 28), catchup=False)

awsGlueOperator = AWSGlueJobOperator(job_name='FIRST_JOB', script_location='https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/path-to-script',s3_bucket='https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/', iam_role_name='AWSGlueServiceRole', dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

awsGlueOperator >> hello_operator
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the GlueOperator you are using uses the [AWS Hook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3504/files#diff-31562106f0b6b3c8d91f1fb7b2f6bcb2R22). Jumping into the source code for that shows that aws keys and such can go in the [extras field as a JSON object](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook.py#L103).
So you can probably just use the `Amazon Web Services` Connection type and fill in the appropriate values there.

Here's what it would look like (in a UI with a modified color and font):
[image]

Comment: login and password for amazon - it's clear, but what should i write in fields host, schema and port or leave it blank?

Comment: I've never used Glue before, but I generally use Host/Schema/Port when connecting to Redshift/some other db, but leave it blank otherwise.

Comment: @Madness could you please explain what did you do after which your issue was resolved?

Comment: @HiranyaDeka sorry for late response. I had provided some extras fields as described in https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/connection/aws.html